# android folder is not showing in flutter project files

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The Android folder is not visible in my Flutter project, even though I created the project. Additionally, when I navigate to the project directory, the folder containing project files and packages also does not show the Android folder. Despite running `flutter doctor` without any issues, I've tried various solutions, including creating the files again, but I'm unable to generate the Android folder.

[image: Screenshot]

Furthermore, when I check the project directory, it lacks the Android folder:

[image: the project directory]

I have diligently followed troubleshooting steps, yet the Android folder remains elusive. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To add Android support for an existing project, run

```
flutter create --platforms android .
```